# how to join or split ip networks with php

Tags: php, network-programming, ip

I have a task that seems to include a subtask. Take two or more ip segments ( could be 192.168.1.32/27, 192.168.1.64/28 and 192.168.1.128/25) and join them into the closest segment (192.168.1.0/24 using the former ip segments). A check if its possible to join the segments must be .

Anyone know if there is a php class with tools that can do that - or a couple of functions likewise?

/Lars

EDIT:
[code]

```
$ip_id_array = array();
$ip_level_array = array();
$ip_segment_array = array();
$ip_cidr_array = array();
$toplevel_array = array();

foreach ($_POST["net_ip_id"] AS $ip_id)
{
    $sql = "
    SELECT
        ip_segments.ip_id,
        ip_segments.ip_segment,
        ip_segments.ip_level,
        ip_segments.ip_cidr
    FROM
        ip_segments
    WHERE
        ip_id = '".$ip_id."'
    ";
    $relip_res = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or cc("ERROR: SQL Select subsegments related", $sql, mysqli_error($db) , $_SESSION["u_id"], $this_document);
    $ip_array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($relip_res);
    $ip_id_array[] = $ip_array["ip_id"];
    $ip_level_array[] = $ip_array["ip_level"];
    $ip_segment_array[] = $ip_array["ip_segment"];
    $ip_cidr_array[] = $ip_array["ip_cidr"];

    if ($ip_array["ip_level"] != 0 && !empty($ip_array["ip_level"]))
    {
        $sql = "
        SELECT
            ip_segments.ip_id,
            ip_segments.ip_segment,
            ip_segments.ip_level,
            ip_segments.ip_cidr
        FROM
            ip_segments
        WHERE
            ip_id = '".$ip_array["ip_level"]."'
        ";
        $relip_res = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or cc("ERROR: SQL Select subsegments related", $sql, mysqli_error($db) , $_SESSION["u_id"], $this_document);
        $toplevel[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($relip_res);
    }
}

$ip_level_array = array_unique($ip_level_array);
$ip_cidr_array = array_unique($ip_cidr_array);
$toplevel = array_unique($toplevel);

if(sizeof($ip_level_array) > 1)
    $field_alerts[] = "IP Segments must be within the same segment.!";
if ($ip_cidr_array[0] <= 1)
    $field_alerts[] = "Subnetmasks must be larger than or equal to 1";
if ($toplevel <= 1)
    $field_alerts[] = "No Toplevel to merge to!";

if (sizeof($field_alerts) < 1)
{
    $new_segment = $ip_id_array[0];
    $new_cidr = $toplevel[0]["ip_cidr"];
}
```

[/code]

Edit:
A segment is toplevel 192.168.1.0/24 (id 1 - level 0)
It can be subnetted into several different types of subnets ranging from /25 and down to /32 (host).
Say we segment to /26. That gives the following:

```
ID, Level, IP, CIDR
2,1,192.168.1.0,26
3,1,192.168.1.64,26
4,1,192.168.1.128,26
5,1,192.168.1.192,26
```

See: http://jodies.de/ipcalc?host=192.168.1.0&mask1=24&mask2=26

What I need is a piece of code that can take an array of id's, look at the segment and cidr and look at the possibility to join the segments to closest supernet (in this case /25 or /24)
Options:

```
Join ID, Result
2,3 => true (/25)
2,4 => false (networks not "next" to each other (a /26 between))
3,4 => false (subsegments will split toplevel (/25) segment
4,5 => true (/25)
```

Let me know if more info is needed.

Comment: How did you come to 0/24 in the last ip?

Comment: (feeling ignorant) what is the criteria to determine that 192.168.1.0/24 is the closest segment in such a case?

Comment: http://www.rjsmith.com/CIDR-Table.html

Comment: One need to look at the segments and calculate the "closeness" of the segments (are the segments close enough to be joined)

Comment: We still don't know what do you have in your database, we only have the code that is doing an query. Also I don't fully understand what are you trying to do. How did you come up with 192.168.1.0/24? Is it related to network class or are you just finding the smallest subnet that encompasses the group of subnets? If it's the second what is the criteria for being "close enough to be joined"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your last edit I think that you want to find optimal summarization for provided subnets.

Let's say that you have subnets from your example:

```
192.168.1.0/26
192.168.1.64/26
192.168.1.128/26
192.168.1.192/26
```

Since all operations involved in calculating subnet properties maybe it's easier to look at binary representation of the subnets:

```
11000000101010000000000100000000
11000000101010000000000101000000
11000000101010000000000110000000
11000000101010000000000111000000
```

The way to check if two subnets can be joined is to look at the last subnet bit. Masking the host part (last 6 bits in this example) the only allowed difference between two subnet IDs in order for them to be joined must be in the last subnet bit (between pipes).

```
1100000010101000000000010|0|hhhhhh
1100000010101000000000010|1|hhhhhh
1100000010101000000000011|0|hhhhhh
1100000010101000000000011|1|hhhhhh
```

In this example first two subnets have the same first 25 bits so they can be joined together. The same stands for last two subnets. But subnets 2 and 3 have a different 25th bit so they could not be joined. So, for two subnets to be joined they need to have the same subnet mask of length `N` and the first `N-1` address bits should be the same.

When implementing this with an array of IPs you need to address two problems:

1. What to do with an array and in which order to go trough it
2. How to pair best possible candidates and check if they can be summarized

and both problems can be solved by structuring and sorting the array. So let's say that you got your array from the database and you want to summarize the subnets.

```
$ips = array(
    array("ip" => "192.168.1.0", "cidr" => "26"),
    array("ip" => "192.168.1.64", "cidr" => "26"),
    array("ip" => "192.168.1.128", "cidr" => "26"),
    array("ip" => "192.168.1.192", "cidr" => "26")
);
```

The way I would solve the problem is to build the array with addresses represented as numbers and CIDR lengths as keys. Note the `& (-1 << (32 - $ips[$i]['cidr'])` part: this is not needed if the addresses in your database **are** subnet addresses, but I included it just for case. That will do a bitwise AND on IP address and subnet mask and calculate the subnet address for any IP.

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($ips); $i++){
    $net = ip2long($ips[$i]['ip']) & (-1 << (32 - $ips[$i]['cidr']));
    $n_ips[$ips[$i]['cidr']][]= $net;
}
```

This will give you `$n_ips` array (which looks like this below) and enable you to sort the array by CIDR and process the smallest subnets first and maybe join that summary with larger subnets later.

```
array
  26 => 
    array
      0 => int -1062731520
      1 => int -1062731456
      2 => int -1062731392
      3 => int -1062731328
```

You should do the same thing with the second level array. Sorting the addresses will place the best possible candidates adjacent to each other. You would then iterate trough each array and check if the subnets can be joined using the rule mentioned before:

Two subnets need to have the same subnet mask of length `N` (which they do since you classified the subnets by the CIDR prefix) and the first `N-1` address bits should be the same. The second thing is easily done by calculating the both subnet address using a 1bit shorter CIDR prefix: `$ip & (-1 << 32 - ($cidr+1))` and checking if they're the same.

So the final function (which takes the `$n_ips` array you made before as an argument) could look like this:

```
function summarize($n_ips){
    $changed = false; // Did you change anything in this iteration?
    $new = array();   // Array with summarized scopes
    krsort($n_ips);  // Sort array keys (CIDR)
    foreach($n_ips as $cidr => $ips){
        sort($n_ips[$cidr]);  // Sort the scopes from lowest to highest
        for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($n_ips[$cidr]); $i++){
            if($n_ips[$cidr][$i] == $n_ips[$cidr][$i+1]){   //Skip if you have two same subnets (not needed if your list of scopes is clean)
                continue;
            }
            if(($n_ips[$cidr][$i] & (-1 << 33 - $cidr)) == ($n_ips[$cidr][$i+1] & (-1 << 33 - $cidr))){ //Are subnet IDs from current and next subnet the same if you have smaller subnet mask?
                $new[$cidr-1][] = $n_ips[$cidr][$i] & (-1 << 33 - $cidr);    //If yes add the summarized subnet to the new array
                $i++;                                                       //Skip the next subnet
                $changed = true;                                            //And raise the changed flag
            }else{
                $new[$cidr][] = $n_ips[$cidr][$i];                          //If not just copy the current subnet
            }
        }
    }
    return $changed ? summarize($new) : $n_ips; //If there were no changes you have the optimized summarization, otherwise summarize the new array
}
```

The output would be the array of summarized subnets with numeric representation of addresses which you can convert to dot-decimal representation:

```
$s_ips = summarize($n_ips)

foreach($s_ips as $cidr => $ips){
    foreach($ips as $ip){
        echo long2ip($ip) . "/" . $cidr . "<br/>";
    }
}
```

You said that you just need true/false if the summarization is possible but i intentionally provided more general answer. You can modify the function to return true only if you have one subnet left in the summarized array.

Comment: @pajaja fantastic answer. May I point out a small bug with out-of-bounds index in `summarize()`, since you are incrementing `$i` twice some times.

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed the solution provided by @pajaja, it has some small issues that I fixed but on top of that this solution does not consider the merge between cidr groups. an example of this is like if in the $n_ip array we have a an ip in a cidr(like /30) that is part of another one in an existing /29 subnet. An example of this is the output of this algorithm that return 193.31.208.0/30 besides 193.31.208.0/28 while 193.31.208.0/30 is part of 193.31.208.0/28.

So my very basic solution to this problem is to break down all the input subnets to /32 and keep the unique /32 values then feed the result to the summarize function to make a aggregated list. I tested this aproach and validated the result with 2 commercial cli tools including "Aggregate" and "netcalc".

Comment: Please explain your answer with examples and code.